# R - Subset of data to get corresponding columns but no duplicates

Tags: r

I have a dataset where the rows are individual crimes. One of the columns is the LSOA code and another is the name of the place. Of course, there are multiple rows with the same name and LSOA. I want to end up with a dataframe that has each area name with the corresponding LSOA code. I have gone round in circles trying to find a way to do this with subset, count, frequencies etc. but either lose one of the columns or it just doesn't work.

This is an example of the dataset.

```
 Code   |    Name      | Crime_Type |   Outcome
----------------------------------------------------
E01000852 Camden 026C     Vehicle     Under investigation
E01000982 Croydon 017C    Other       Unable to prosecute
E01000982 Croydon 017C    Other       Under investigation
E01003950 Southwark 032B  Assault     Status update unavailable
E01003950 Southwark 032B  Violence    Under investigation   
E01003950 Southwark 032B  Other       Under investigation
```

This is what I would like my output to be

```
Code  |    Name      
-----------------
E01000852 Camden 026C
E01000982 Croydon 017C
E01003950 Southwark 032B
```

I have tried the following, which worked but I lose the name column.

```
name <- as.data.frame(table(data$Code))
```

Any help appreciated.

```
dput(head(data, 10)

structure(list(code = c("E01000013", "E01000852", "E01000982", 
"E01000982", "E01000996", "E01001227", "E01001591", "E01001751", 
"E01002848", "E01003171"), name = c("Barking and Dagenham 013A", 
"Camden 026C", "Croydon 017C", "Croydon 017C", "Croydon 009C", 
"Ealing 019D", "Greenwich 012C", "Hackney 021D", "Kensington and Chelsea 015C", 
"Lambeth 020B"), crime_type = c("Public order", "Vehicle crime", 
"Other crime", "Violence and sexual offences", "Violence and sexual offences", 
"Violence and sexual offences", "Violence and sexual offences", 
"Violence and sexual offences", "Other crime", "Violence and sexual offences"
), outcome_category = c("Unable to prosecute suspect", "Further investigation is not in the public interest", 
"Under investigation", "Under investigation", "Under investigation", 
"Status update unavailable", "Status update unavailable", "Under investigation", 
"Under investigation", "Unable to prosecute suspect"), outcome_recode = c("0", 
"1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "0"), density = c(8927, 16348, 
11760, 11760, 11302, 8537, 10382, 11269, 17929, 16309), population = c(1855, 
2037, 1610, 1610, 1189, 1476, 2095, 1732, 1472, 1701), IMD_value = c(2, 
6, 5, 5, 5, 8, 3, 5, 3, 4), urban_rural_class = c("Urban major conurbation", 
"Urban major conurbation", "Urban major conurbation", "Urban major conurbation", 
"Urban major conurbation", "Urban major conurbation", "Urban major conurbation", 
"Urban major conurbation", "Urban major conurbation", "Urban major conurbation"
)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You want only unique Names? What happens to the rest of the info?

Comment: I don't need the other two columns, just the first two.

Comment: Could you provide your data with `dput(head(df,n))`? Did you try `unique(df$code)`?

Comment: Seems different from example but try `df %>% 
  filter(!duplicated(name)) %>% 
  select(1:2)` using `dplyr`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(code, name) %>% slice_head() %>% select(1:2)

# A tibble: 9 x 2
# Groups:   code, name [9]
  code      name                       
  <chr>     <chr>                      
1 E01000013 Barking and Dagenham 013A  
2 E01000852 Camden 026C                
3 E01000982 Croydon 017C               
4 E01000996 Croydon 009C               
5 E01001227 Ealing 019D                
6 E01001591 Greenwich 012C             
7 E01001751 Hackney 021D               
8 E01002848 Kensington and Chelsea 015C
9 E01003171 Lambeth 020B
```

Or in base R

```
df[match(unique(df$code), df$code), 1:2]

        code                        name
1  E01000013   Barking and Dagenham 013A
2  E01000852                 Camden 026C
3  E01000982                Croydon 017C
5  E01000996                Croydon 009C
6  E01001227                 Ealing 019D
7  E01001591              Greenwich 012C
8  E01001751                Hackney 021D
9  E01002848 Kensington and Chelsea 015C
10 E01003171                Lambeth 020B
```

Here row numbers will be as per original dataframe